# jQuery не находит элементы после их добавление через append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код

```
$.each(response, function (index, object) {
                        var slide_item = '<div class="slide" style = "vertical-align: middle;">' +
                                '<img src="http:\/\/remont.qwerq.ru\/' + object.path + '">' +
                                '<span class="slide-text">' +
                                '<span class="icon icon-left-nav"></span>' + 'anything' +
                                '</span>' +
                                '</div>';


                        $('#mySlideGroup').append(slide_item);
                    });
```

Добавилось 3 слайда. Далее выполняется такой скрипт:

```
//Подгонка изображений под размер слайдера
            jQuery(function ($) {

                function fix_size() {
                    var images = $('.slide img');
                    images.each(setsize);

                    function setsize() {
                        var img = $(this),
                                img_dom = img.get(0),
                                container = img.parents('.slide');
                        if (img_dom.complete) {
                            resize();
                        } else
                            img.one('load', resize);

                        function resize() {
                            if ((container.width() / container.height()) < (img_dom.width / img_dom.height)) {
                                img.width('100%');
                                img.height('auto');
                                return;
                            }
                            img.height('100%');
                            img.width('auto');
                            //
                        }
                    }
                }
                $(window).on('resize', fix_size);
                fix_size();
            });
```

Примечательно, что `$('.slide img');` , равно как и `$('.slide');`возвращает пустой объект. Не вкурю никак, помогите разобраться.

Comment: `var images = $('.slide img').getAttr('src');` - вернется линк, само изображение не вернется

Comment: До этого еще не доходя, почему  $('.slide') возвращает пустой объект?

Comment: А что он должен возвращать?

Comment: Я полагаю он должен вернуть массив из трех элементов. Нет? Я новичок, делайте мне скидку)

Comment: `console.log($('#mySlideGroup').length, $('#mySlideGroup').find(".slide").length);` - ?

Comment: $('#mySlideGroup').length = 1, $('#mySlideGroup').find(".slide").length = 0

Comment: в Вашем коде есть что-то, что не показано в вопросе. Что выводит `console.log($('#mySlideGroup').find(".slide").length);` и `console.log($('#mySlideGroup').html());` сразу после вызова `append`?

Comment: 1 и 3.. Странность в том что описанные функции объявлены в рамках выполнения одного скрипта, и между ними ничего нет. Разве что append выполняется в success-функции ajax запроса.

Comment: Где-то Вы очищаете Ваш контейнер или убираете класс `slide`. Ищите.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос. Посмотрите как все выглядит вместе.

Comment: console.log($('#mySlideGroup').length);
                    console.log($('#mySlideGroup').find(".slide").length);
                }
            });

            //Подгонка изображений под размер слайдера
            

                function fix_size() {
                    console.log($('#mySlideGroup').length);
                    console.log($('#mySlideGroup').find(".slide").length);
Теперь картина такая в консоли 1, 0, 1, 3 . Складывается впечатление, что fixsize() срабатывает быстрее, чем завершается append

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, следующая за ajax запросом функция fixsize выполнялась раньше, чем выполнялся append(). Решено путем вложения функции fixsize в функцию success ajax-запроса.